# How do I let declarations from one header file access three separate viewcontrollers?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5, header-files, declaration

I am making a single-view application on xCode 5, and I would like to have a setting where the user can select their car's colour and the colour of the background.  I have made it work using 2 view controllers; 1 as a main menu and 1 as choosing colour, background, and playing the game. I am pretty sure this is bad practice for an app like this, so I would like to find a different way to do the same. I have it so that the background selection and game objects are "hidden" while selecting car colour. And then when selecting background, the car colour and game objects are hidden. and then when playing the game, the car colours and backgrounds are hidden. I know this is terrible structure, which is why I would like to get an answer as to how to link up the same declarations to 3 separate viewcontrollers. Or at least an alternative that isn't so messy. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of dealing with this is to store such values (properties) in your AppDelegate class, or as your apps grow in a custom Data Model. That way every class you create will be able to access and change the values another class sets. It's like having a "global variable".

It's easy to do this in AppDelegate though for smaller apps:

- create the public properties for your background and car colours in AppDelegate.h
- in your View Controller, import AppDelegate.h
- in your View Controller, create a reference to your app's AppDelegate like so:

  AppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

Now you can access myAppDelegate.yourProperty = xxx and get and set your values. This will grab a reference to your current AppDelegate and all its (public) properties.

As you get more into it and as your apps grow in size and complexity, you'll create your own data model class (or use Core Data) to keep track of app wide changes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you a lot, one more question - Do I import "AppDelegate.h" into my viewcontroller.m or viewcontroller.h file?

Comment: Into the .h file. Add it just under the current #import statement.